# Flutter nested menu flying left and right

Tags: flutter, animation, menu

How to implement the flying left or right animation for nested menu in flutter? I have a bottom sheet like the below one. I want the bottom sheet content (not the bottom sheet itself) to flying left, and new content will fly in from the right side when clicking the item "select your address type". This is common behaviour in web for nested menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]I found a working solution by using **stack** and **AnimatedPositioned**. The tricky part is to calculate all nested menu's left position(you may use the right position as well). It's similar to how a image carousel works.